# Emacs ftp upload on save like in sublimetext?

Tags: emacs, ftp, sublimetext

I used sublemtext and I have made the switch to using emacs.

I love that you can completely never leave emacs while working. With that said there is a lot to learn. I am trying to find out a way to duplicate my workflow for pushing files from my local server to the remote for numerous projects. A lot of my clients servers are on shared hosting and I cant use ssh.

With sublimetext I had a sftp.json file within my project locally and it had the ftp details for the server. So anytime I am working in a local dir I can just save and it uploads.

One of the main reasons I like this vs just editing directly on the server is I use compass to watch projects and compile. So I can make a change and it compiles. I then push the compiled file up.

I am aware of ange-ftp being built in I believe. I have made a connection to my server, but its just directly editing obviously.

Could some of you advanced emacs folks help me achieve the same setup?

Comment: TRAMP is the most common way to edit remote files in Emacs, but I'm not sure that I understand the Compass bit. What exactly is Compass watching? Do you have a full copy of the source code locally?

Comment: This explains compass really quick - http://compass-style.org/help/ - I can include a json file that sublimetext has for their ftp package.

Comment: To be clear, you've got a full copy of the source locally, and you're editing Sass files like `file.scss`. When you save `file.scss`, Compass generates `file.css`, and you then want your editor to automatically FTP `file.css` to your server?

Comment: Can you use rsync or something similar?  Emacs (gasp) isn't really the right tool for this job.

Comment: I'm not familiar with using rsync, but doesnt that have to be installed on the server too? I have limitations with shared hosting environments. Thats why that other work flow worked so well for me.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is something your editor should be doing. You could mount your remote directory somewhere on your local machine and have Compass save built CSS there as [suggested here with OSX](http://blog.rainbird.me/post/41730281659/using-sass-with-codekit-transmit-remote-stylesheets). If you're on Linux, [FUSE and CurlFtpFS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mount_FTP) can be used the same way. And [WebDrive can help if you're on Windows](http://serverfault.com/questions/6079/how-can-i-mount-an-ftp-to-a-drive-letter-in-windows).

Comment: Mounting remote directory to local is the best way in my opinion. I also occasionally use `git-ftp`. It uses git to determine files that changed from last commit and update them via FTP, you don't need to install anything on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would likely make a after-save-hook in emacs with a function to upload the file to the remote location. You could define a login function perhaps using .netrc[.gpg] if you are concerned about security, and have your after-save-hook call that to upload the file.

Here is some info on [Standard Emacs Hooks](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Standard-Hooks.html), and another page of the GNU manual about [Saving Buffers](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Saving-Buffers.html#Saving-Buffers).

One other consideration/thought is to restrict that functionality to a particular directory, like a project directory. For example, anything in /home/user/workspace/projecta/ would get uploaded to host1:/projecta, etc.

Comment: This sounds great! This would be good if I can setup each project with the connection details specific to each. They would all be under a parent project dir like you mentioned. But I have a good amount of clients, and new clients often that I would be setting this up for.

Comment: The tricky bit here is that you *don't* want to upload after you save. You want to upload *after Compass does its thing*. There's likely a delay between saving your `.scss` file and Compass generating the corresponding `.css` file, so you may occasionally get the old version uploaded to the server. Generating your CSS file within the hook instead of with Compass should help with that though.